# Setting a params hash to a variable within the controller (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, parameters

I'm very new to rails and have this fairly basic question:

I have a form that takes in an array:

```
<td><%= fields_for "days" do |form| %>
            M: <%= form.check_box "", {}, 'M', ''  %>
            T: <%= form.check_box "", {}, 'T', '' %>
            W: <%= form.check_box "", {}, 'W', '' %>
            Th: <%= form.check_box "", {}, 'Th', '' %>
            F: <%= form.check_box "", {}, 'F', '' %>
    <% end %>
```

This should be accessible through params[:days]. How can I assign params[:days] to a variable within the controller? @days is **not** correct here, right? (There's no Days object, so there's no instance of that object). What should go in the [correct_variable] slot below?

```
[correct_variable] = params[:days]
```

Thanks!

---

In response to comments:

I tried using @days, but for some reason it wouldn't get called where I'd like it to. In particular, I'd like to pass it to my Search model:

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :day, :units, :instructor

  def courses
    @courses ||= find_courses
  end 

  private 

    def find_courses
      Course.find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
    end   

    def day_conditions
      ["courses.day LIKE ?", "%"+ @days.join("%")+"%"] 
    end
```

I first instantiate @days in my courses controller (which is connected, through the index method, to a partial that uses an instance of the Search object.

---

More code:

From courses/index.html.erb:

```
<% if @search.save %>
    <div id = "results_scroll">
        <%= render :partial => 'searches/search_results' %>
    </div>
<% else %>
```

From search_results partial:

```
<% "Search" %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th align="left" width="25%"><%= 'Name' %></th>
        <th align="left" width="10%"><%= 'Number' %></th>
        <th align="left" width="20%"><%= 'Instructor' %></th>
        <th align="left" width="10%"><%= 'Room' %></th>
        <th align="left" width="5%"><%=  'Day' %></th>
        <th align="left" width="5%"><%=  'Units' %></th>
        <th align="left" width="15%"><%=  'Time' %></th>
        <th align="left" width="10%"><%=  'Limitations' %></th>
    </tr>
<%= render :partial => @search_show.courses %>
</table>
```

From the courses controller (this has the @search_show variable).

```
  def index
    @courses = Course.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
    @search = Search.new 
    @search_show = Search.last
    @title = "List"
    @days = params[:days]
```

Finally, the _course.html.erb partial:

```
<tr>
   <td><%= course.name %></td>
   <td><%= course.number %></td>
   <td><%= course.instructor %></td>
   <td><%= course.room %></td>
   <td><%= course.day %></td>
   <td><%= course.units %></td>
   <td><%= course.time %></td>
   <td><%= course.limitations %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Show', course %></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% on what you're asking.  What is the problem you have with `@days = params[:days]`? You say there is no "Days object", but isn't that expected value? If there is no @days then you won't be overwriting something

Comment: Added some commentary to my question. Hope that helps.

Comment: is this in the courses controller? where are you making the partial call? inside of courses/index.html.erb? where are you routing to? "courses#index"?

Comment: This is actually from my Search model. Within my courses/index.html.erb I call a "search results" partial, which calls a @search_show.courses partial. [at]search_show is a variable I have under the index method of my Courses controller, and it calls the last search. I know that's a lot, so I'll try to add some more to my question. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but there is some problems with how you are trying to access your `@days` variable you set in the controller.

```
# your controller 
...
def index
  ...
  @days = params[:days]

# your model
...
private

def day_conditions
  ["courses.day LIKE ?", "%"+ @days.join("%")+"%"] 
end
```

The `@days`, in your model, you are calling is not going to access the `@days` in your controller. Each `@days` belongs to their respective instances.

You should find a method of sending the `@days` from your controller into your models, instead of using global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using a $days global variable instead of @days.